# Parallel requests fails on a flask application of multiple deep learning models

Tags: python, flask

I was facing a memory problem with my flask application where the memory was not released to the OS after each request. The memory kept accumulating and eventually, it would clot up and the program would go out of memory.

To solve this problem, I used multiprocessing and handled the calculations in a separate process.

```
def process_yolact(self, front, side):
        try:
            manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
            return_dict = manager.dict()

            def worker_process(return_dic, front, side):
                front_mask, front = self.obj_yolact.run_yolact(front, 'f')
                side_mask, side = self.obj_yolact.run_yolact(side, 's')
                gc.collect()
                return_dic['1'] = True
                return_dic['2'] = front
                return_dic['3'] = side
                return_dic['4'] = front_mask
                return_dic['5'] = side_mask

            p = Process(target=worker_process, args=(return_dict, front, side))
            p.start()
            p.join()
            return return_dict.values()
        except:
            return False, None, None, None, None
```

```
def process_maskrcnn(self, front, side):
        try:
            manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
            return_dict = manager.dict()

            def worker_process(return_dic, front, side):
                frontrcnnmask, frontmask = self.obj_maskrcnn.run_maskrcnn(front, 'f')
                sidercnnmask, sidemask = self.obj_maskrcnn.run_maskrcnn(side, 's')
                gc.collect()
                return_dic['1'] = True
                return_dic['2'] = frontrcnnmask
                return_dic['3'] = sidercnnmask
                return_dic['4'] = frontmask
                return_dic['5'] = sidemask

            p = Process(target=worker_process, args=(return_dict, front, side))
            p.start()
            p.join()
            return return_dict.values()

        except:
            return False, None, None, None, None
```

I used processes and end them after each request.

Now, when I send multiple requests at a time I get output for few and few come out without any output.

I tried handling using `gunicorn` so that requests are handled in threads but didn't get lucky. How do we can solve such a problem?

Currently, I am using `waitress` to serve the application on the server.

So that multiple requests at a time can be processed without any hiccups.

Comment: Could you please provide information on your platform? Multiprocessing and threading behave quite differently on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I am using LInux @IronFarm